# Check Valid Time in Userform

Tags: regex, excel, vba, userform, error-checking

I am trying to error check in a userform where I want to be able to check that the time that was entered is a valid time expression (00:00 or 00 PM) as I am sending it through a TimeValue command for the output so that the time is standardized. If the value entered is not a valid expression I will have an error message display and allow to reenter a valid expression. I am not sure if this is something I can accomplish with Regex or if there is a simpler option. I have attached my code below.

> ```
> Private Sub CommandButton_OK_Click()
> Dim emptyrow As Long
>
> 'Error Check
> If NameText.Value = "" Then
>     MsgBox "Please Enter Valid Name", vbOKOnly
>     Exit Sub
> End If
>
> 'Make Sheet 1 Active
> Sheet1.Activate
>
> 'Determine emptyRow
> emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E:E")) + 1
>
> 'Convert Time of Inspection to Time Value
> TimeText.Value = TimeValue(TimeText.Value)
>
> 'Transfer Info
> Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = DateText.Value
> Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = NameText.Value
> Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = ShiftText.Value
> Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = TimeText.Value
>
> If CornNo.Value = True Then
>     Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = "No"
> Else
>     Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = "Yes"
> End If
>
> If SurgeNo.Value = True Then
>     Cells(emptyrow, 10).Value = "No"
> Else
>     Cells(emptyrow, 10).Value = "Yes"
> End If
>
> If MillNo.Value = True Then
>     Cells(emptyrow, 11).Value = "No"
> Else
>     Cells(emptyrow, 11).Value = "Yes"
> End If
>
> If FBedNo.Value = True Then
>     Cells(emptyrow, 12).Value = "No"
> Else
>     Cells(emptyrow, 12).Value = "Yes"
> End If
>
> If DDGOutNo.Value = True Then
>     Cells(emptyrow, 13).Value = "No"
> Else
>     Cells(emptyrow, 13).Value = "Yes"
> End If
>
> If DDGInNo.Value = True Then
>     Cells(emptyrow, 14).Value = "No"
> Else
>     Cells(emptyrow, 14).Value = "Yes"
> End If
>
> Unload Me
>
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may want to user error handling with the `On Error GoTo Label` statement, I  think that this will get what you want done

```
    Private Sub CommandButton_OK_Click()

    If nameText.Value = "" Then GoTo InvalidName

    ''  Do some stuff

    On Error GoTo InvalidTime
    Let TimeText.Value = TimeValue(TimeText.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ''  Do some more stuff

    Let Cells(emptyrow, 9).Value = IIf(CornNo.Value = True, "No", "Yes")

    ''  Do even more stuff

    Exit Sub

InvalidName:
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Name", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub

InvalidTime:
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Valid Time", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: This is much easier than trying to construct a set of `Regex` patterns

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed